# Finding independent set in a cubic graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization, np-complete

This question is a reference request. I am pretty sure that finding an independent set of size at least $k$ in $G$, where $G$ is a cubic graph, is an NP-hard problem. However, I did not find any source where the result is proven. Please share with the source information if you know where it is proven.

Comment: The first link in my answer is the fourth result when you search for 'np independent set regular graphs' on Google Scholar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maximum independent sets in 3- and 4-regular Hamiltonian graphs](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2010.05.028) by Fleischner, Sabidussi, and Sarvanov proves more: that the independent set problem is NP-complete for $3$-regular Hamiltonian planar graphs. (It follows that it's NP-complete for $3$-regular graphs in general, since the same reduction works if we forget that its result is Hamiltonian and planar.)

This is not the first $3$-regular graph proof. The authors write:

> That MIS is an NP-complete problem for $3$-regular Hamiltonian graphs is probably a well-known piece of graph-theoretic folklore. Not having found any reference in the literature, we include here a proof, at the same time strengthening the result...

Also, they cite Gary and Johnson's *Computers and Intractability* (p. 194) for the result when the graphs are $3$-regular and planar but not Hamiltonian.